# How to send a text message to a PC whose IP address I know?

Tags: protocols, ip-address, network-protocols, bittorrent

I know this is a weird question, but I would like to know if there is a way to send a text message to a PC whose IP address I know.

**For instance**, I am downloading a file through torrent from a PC on the net.

Through torrent I can know the IP address of this PC, and I want send a text message to the person who owns this PC.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you imagine if it were possible?

Comment: Are you working for the RIAA? If so leave us alone!

Comment: Does PC mean computer?  What does message mean?

Comment: Something like net send? That would show a message box, but as others have stated I highly doubt it would be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is No. You would have to send that through an open port on the recipients PC which a firewall would surely block (Windows Firewall, router, etc..). Even if it didn't get blocked - you'd need something to turn your message from zeros and ones to text - and display it on the users monitor. You'll need to write a software client to do that, and get that person to install it.

There are probably some black-hat techniques to do this, but again, you're talking advanced software and network penetration.

Comment: Windows XP originally allowed for sending messages via the use of Windows Messaging Service: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messenger_service

Comment: You still have to be on the same LAN - unless you hack in and install a client to act as a proxy. You can also do it as an administrator in a domain environment - but it doesn't really apply to the question